# Can I create a corpus from a collection of strings in NLTK?

Tags: collections, nltk, corpus

Is there a way to create a corpus without having to have items in files. For instance, I want to manipulate Tweets or paragraphs that I am grabbing from the web. Can I do something like

```
myCorpus = MyCorpus([
    ('id', 'item', 'category'), 
    ('id', 'item', 'category'),
    ('id', 'item', 'category'), 
    ... ])
```

Or

```
myCorpus.add('id', 'item', 'category')
```

The purpose is to manipulate the corpus with existing NLTK capabilities. I checked `TextCollection` but it seems that it doesn't handle categories.

Answer (score -1):

Why not just write the strings out to a file or files and then process them as a corpus?

Comment: It may be faster to keep things in memory. For example, if you're scraping content from the web.